# A question of divergence rate

Tags: limits-and-convergence

I meet an expression as following:
$$L_{N}=\frac{C_{2N}^{N}}{2^{2N}}=\frac{(2N)!}{N!N!2^{2N}}$$

My conjecture is that:
$$\lim_{N \to \infty}L_{N}=0$$

It seems to be an easy question, but how to show it simply?

Comment: Use the aymptotic of the Catalan numbers to get that the fraction behaves like $(N+1)/N^{3/2}$.

Comment: If $k\approx N$, then $C_{2N}^k\approx C_{2N}^N$.

Comment: Note : $L_n$ is the ratio of the product of the first $n$ odd numbers to the product of the first $n$ even numbers. Possibly, that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Erdos gives ${{2n}\choose{n}}4^{-n}<1/\sqrt{2n+1}$ in his book with Suranyi. For an inductive proof one needs to show 
$$
\frac{2n(2n-1)}{4n^2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}
$$
which simplifies to $\sqrt{2n-1}\sqrt{2n+1}<2n$.

Comment: Komjath : could you please mention the name of the book.

Comment: Yes: Topics in the Theory of Numbers, http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387953205 See also at google.books https://books.google.hu/books/about/Topics_in_the_Theory_of_Numbers.html?id=MTefj5-5OwEC&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 1):

You're right. It is easy with [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)
$$N! \sim \sqrt{2\pi N}\left(\frac{N}e\right)^N$$
so that 
$$L_N=\frac{(2N)!}{N!N!2^{2N}} \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi(2N)}(2N)^{2N}}{e^{2N}2^{2N}}\frac{e^{2N}}{(2\pi N)N^{2N}}=\frac1{\sqrt{\pi N}}\rightarrow 0$$
as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Thanks very much! Stirling's approximation is so powerful!